# RxSwift Difference between Signal and Driver

Tags: swift

Cant understand the difference of behavior Signal and Driver.

As i read "A Signal is similar to Driver with one difference, it does not replay the latest event on subscription". I'm trying to reproduce this difference. Cant understand why in this case Driver did not print "b" firstly

```
        var relay = PublishRelay<String>()
        
        relay.accept("a")
        
        relay.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "err").drive(onNext: { val in
           print(val)
        }).disposed(by: bag)

        relay.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: "err").emit(onNext: { val in
            print(val)
        }).disposed(by: bag)

        relay.accept("b")
//Signal print : b , Driver print : b
```

And in this case "Here" printed two times on subscribe

```
         textfield.rx.text.asDriver().drive(onNext: { sd in
            print("Here")
        }).disposed(by: bag)


        textfield.rx.text.asSignal(onErrorJustReturn: "").emit(onNext: { sd in
            print("Here")
        }).disposed(by: bag)
```

If i do smth wrong please help me with example to understand the difference , thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The difference between a `Signal` and a `Driver` in RxCocoa is that Driver is designed to be used in UI bindings and always delivers events on the main thread, while Signal can be used in any context and delivers events on whatever thread they were created on.

Regarding your code example, the reason why "b" is printed by both `Driver` and `Signal` is that the `PublishRelay` does not have any replay functionality. Therefore, when you call `relay.accept("a")` it immediately emits "a" to any subscribers, including the ones subscribed after the event was emitted. When you call `relay.accept("b")`, it emits "b" to all subscribers, including the ones subscribed before the event was emitted.

Regarding the "Here" example, `Driver` and `Signal` behave differently because they have different scheduling. `Driver` always delivers events on the main thread, whereas `Signal` delivers events on the thread they were created on. Therefore, in this case, "Here" is printed twice when using Signal because the `textfield.rx.text` observable was created on the main thread and the `emit` method delivers events on the same thread. On the other hand, when using `Driver`, "Here" is printed only once because the `drive` method always delivers events on the main thread.

TLDR;

`Driver` always delivers events on the main thread, whereas `Signal` delivers events on the thread they were created on.
`Driver` has replay functionality, which means that it always emits the latest event to any new subscribers. `Signal` does not have this functionality.

Comment: Actually I think Signal is also a main scheduler. The only difference is Signal does not replay the last element when subscribed to. So it's actually a great candidate for button taps for example or even controller life cycle events since the pipline would be setup prior to any of these happening and there would be no initial value/event.